# Regular Expressions on Hardcoded URLs in Xcode

Tags: regex, xcode

I would like to run a regular expression through my entire Xcode project. Currently, I have about 80 instances of an NSString that contains a hardcoded domain.

I would like to change this so that I can easily change the host website to my testing server. I have included an example below:

Here is an example of my hardcoded string:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/assets/page.php?
user=%@&token=%@“, user, token];
```

I would like to make it so that I can include a simple variable that would allow me to change my host that would look like this:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/assets/page.php?
user=%@&token=%@“, host_variable, user, token];
```

I cannot do a simple find and replace because I often pass different variables to the URL. I believe I would need a regular expression to do this correctly. Any ideas would be very helpful!

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace

```
(strURL = \[[^\]]+)http://www\.website\.com([^\]"]+")
```

with

```
\1%@\2, host_variable
```

- `\[[^\]]+` is a literal `[`, followed by anything but a closing `]`
- `[^\]"]` is any character except a `]` or a `"`

The idea is to capture the content of `strURL` up to the beginning of the URL, then everything in the string up to the closing quote.

We then replace it with what we captured in the first group (ie everything before `http...`), followed by `%@`, followed by everything inside the quote after `website.com` (the second group), followed by the `host_variable`.

You can play around with the idea [here](http://regex101.com/r/uB9vN0).

Would that solve your issue?

Comment: Wow- you're awesome!!! Ok, so one additional question - what if the name of the NSString is changed? any way to handle that?

Comment: @user2905222, Well technically you don't need the `strURL`, it all depends on your data: you want to find some anchor that is unique to the pattern you want to change. For example you could change the regex to `(\[NSString [^\]]+?)http://www\.website\.com([^\]"]+")`, forcing the string to have both `[NSString` and `www.website.com` to be selected (see [result](http://regex101.com/r/cX3xV1)). `(\[[^\]]+)http://www\.website\.com([^\]"]+")` can even be enough: just be sure you don't match fields you don't want to.